# Magento 2 : Sort product collection by option values

Tags: magento2

We need to sort ordering on option values. for example Color is attribute and values are Red, Green, Blue then when we sort it should sort by alphabetically. So Blue, Green, Red results should come.

I hope you understand the problem. Default magento sort gives results based on option id not alphabetically.

Ref Issue:https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/issues/450

Answer (score 0):

EDIT; I think I misread.

If you wish to sort a product collection by an attribute then add this to the collection:

addAttributeToSort('attribute_code', 'desc')

If you're meaning that you wish for the options to be sorted alphabetically on the front end then you need to re-order them in the admin panel.

So click on stores in the sidebar and select 'product' under the attributes bit, select your 'colour' attribute and re-order them manually.

Comment: https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/issues/450

Comment: Ahh, I see - so the issue is outstanding and you wish to have a fix?  I think might be a good idea to add to your main post.

Comment: main post mens?

Comment: sorry your original post - I can see you've added it now :)

Comment: @BAF, Will this sort the products with option values? How can i sort as like below only load Red on top and rest followed by it